# Generate MD5 and SHA1

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the below function to generate an MD5\SH1 hash for SQL backup files.
This works well, has progress report etc but is slow if using large files.

Could I generate the MD5 at the same time as SH1 rather than having to process the file twice, doubling the time taken? What about converting an MD5 result to SHA1?

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text


Public Class ASyncFileHashAlgorithm
Protected hashAlgorithm As HashAlgorithm
Protected m_hash As Byte()
Protected cancel As Boolean = False
Protected m_bufferSize As Integer = 4096
Public Delegate Sub FileHashingProgressHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As FileHashingProgressArgs)
Public Event FileHashingProgress As FileHashingProgressHandler

Public Sub New(ByVal hashAlgorithm As HashAlgorithm)
    Me.hashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm
End Sub

Public Function ComputeHash(ByVal stream As Stream) As Byte()
    cancel = False
    m_hash = Nothing
    Dim _bufferSize As Integer = m_bufferSize
    ' this makes it impossible to change the buffer size while computing  
    Dim readAheadBuffer As Byte(), buffer As Byte()
    Dim readAheadBytesRead As Integer, bytesRead As Integer
    Dim size As Long, totalBytesRead As Long = 0

    size = stream.Length
    readAheadBuffer = New Byte(_bufferSize - 1) {}
    readAheadBytesRead = stream.Read(readAheadBuffer, 0, _
                                     readAheadBuffer.Length)

    totalBytesRead += readAheadBytesRead

    Do
        bytesRead = readAheadBytesRead
        buffer = readAheadBuffer

        readAheadBuffer = New Byte(_bufferSize - 1) {}
        readAheadBytesRead = stream.Read(readAheadBuffer, 0, _
                                         readAheadBuffer.Length)

        totalBytesRead += readAheadBytesRead

        If readAheadBytesRead = 0 Then
            hashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        Else
            hashAlgorithm.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, buffer, 0)
        End If

        RaiseEvent FileHashingProgress(Me, New _
                             FileHashingProgressArgs(totalBytesRead, size))
    Loop While readAheadBytesRead <> 0 AndAlso Not cancel

    If cancel Then
        Return InlineAssignHelper(m_hash, Nothing)
    End If

    Return InlineAssignHelper(m_hash, hashAlgorithm.Hash)
End Function

Public Property BufferSize() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_bufferSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_bufferSize = value
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Hash() As Byte()
    Get
        Return m_hash
    End Get
End Property

'Public Sub Cancel()
'    cancel = True
'End Sub

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Dim hex As String = ""
    For Each b As Byte In Hash
        hex += b.ToString("x2")
    Next

    Return hex
End Function
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, _
                                                 ByVal value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
End Function
End Class


Public Class FileHashingProgressArgs
Inherits EventArgs
Public Property TotalBytesRead() As Long
    Get
        Return m_TotalBytesRead
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        m_TotalBytesRead = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_TotalBytesRead As Long
Public Property Size() As Long
    Get
        Return m_Size
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Long)
        m_Size = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Size As Long

Public Sub New(ByVal totalBytesRead__1 As Long, ByVal size__2 As Long)
    TotalBytesRead = totalBytesRead__1
    Size = size__2
End Sub
End Class
```

The following is how I'm generating a hash using the above:

```
Shared hasher As New ASyncFileHashAlgorithm(SHA1.Create())

Private Function Test(Byval (strFilePathAndName, as String)


Dim stream As IO.Stream = DirectCast(File.Open(strFilePathAndName, _
                                               FileMode.Open), Stream)

        AddHandler hasher.FileHashingProgress, _
                   AddressOf OnFileHashingProgress

        Dim t = New Thread(AddressOf hasher.ComputeHash)
        t.Start(stream)
        While t.IsAlive
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While


        'LblMD5.Text = hasher.ToString???
        LblSHA1.Text = hasher.ToString

        stream.Dispose()

End Sub

Public Sub OnFileHashingProgress(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                 ByVal e As FileHashingProgressArgs)

    SetControlPropertyValue(uxChildForm.ProgressBar, "Position", _
                            CInt(e.TotalBytesRead / e.Size * 100))

End Sub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want BOTH hash functions? Wouldn't SHA be enough? And you cannot convert MD5 to SHA or vice versa.

Comment: Both values are generated and passed to a client who uses either MD5 or SHA to verify the backup. In an ideal world they would all use one method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `ToString` method may create tremendous overhead for large strings since concatenation is expensive (it creates large temporary buffer) and you do it often. Use a `StringBuilder` (initialised with the correct size) instead.