# MD5 and Sh1 and debug keystrok in eclipse .?

Tags: android, eclipse

how to search and sorry find MD5 and Sh1 and debug keystrok in eclipse .?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate MD5 and SHA1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138401/generate-md5-and-sha1)

Comment: Ctrl+W PREFERENCE+BUILD yes i search myself hurrey!

Comment: no abhinav i am not generate it buy cmd ........

Answer (score 0):

You can find keystore in your system at this path:
    ~/.android/debug.keystore
    To fetch SHA-1 and MD5, you can use this command
    keytool -list -v -keystore "or"